# Вывод рандомных чисел в диапазоне

Tags: javascript

Имеется следующий вопрос. Нужно сделать функцию, которая выводит числа в введенном диапазоне. Такую функцию сделал, при вводе двух значений, работает норм. Но возникает проблема, если ввожу только одно число, она не работает, т.к. требует и второе. Пробовал делать что-то типа проверки через if. И если второе число == underfind, то min == max, а min == 1, в свою очередь. (если введено только одно число, то оно становится максимальным, а минимальным стает единица), но тогда вообще бред выходит.

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  return Math.round(rand);
}
alert( randomInteger(prompt(), prompt()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Только порядок поменял. сначала макс потом мин

```js
function randomInteger(max=1,min=1) {
  return Math.round(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
}
alert( randomInteger(+prompt(), +prompt()));
```